# grunt-contrib-jasmine angularjs module-not-available error

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, phantomjs, grunt-contrib-jasmine

I have a script that looks like this:

```
angular.module('Game').constant('WHITE_PIECE', '\u26C0')
                      ... more lines ...
                      .constant('WHITE_KING', '\u26C1')
(end of file)
```

When I run `grunt jasmine`, I get the classic error, `Module 'Game' is not  available! You either misspelled...`.  Oddly though, I'm positive that module is being declared. If I move the code to the end of the file where the `'Game'` module is declared, it works.  If I move the code to the end of a different file, which declares a service for the `'Game'` module, it works. I get no errors in my browser.  Is this phantomjs being dumb? Is it a bug in Grunt-contrib-jasmine?

I put console.log statements before this file and before the file which declares the Game module; this showed that the constants file is being interpreted before the Game file. However, I thought Angular was clever enough to figure that out.  Do I need to tell grunt-jasmine-contrib exactly which order to load my scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on more Googling, I believe this to be a bug and not a mistake.  The only solution is to force the correct order of script interpretation, which unfortunately negates the convenience of the jasmine globstar source pattern (e.g. `**/*.js`).